# adding authorization header of static values with every request

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular7

I am using Angular 7 for a web applications and there are more than 50 APIs. Now I need to add `Authorization Bearer {token}` with every request which I send.

Is there a way to add it globally without i.e. without changing every APIs call.

`Authorization Bearer {token}` would be same for all APIs. Is there any chance of adding default header via routing.

Comment: You will have to implement a Http Interceptor like this https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is - using interceptors. You can read more about them here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

You can find practical guide to your case here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6